# HTML Padding white space

Tags: html

I need a second pair of eyes, if someone could help me please.

I have uploaded my index page to this site http://preview.tinyurl.com/ct9whug

If you could have a look at my source code/css and see what the problem is, as there is a white space at the top of my web page (about 35px in height), and I can't seem to find what the problem is.

Comment: have you tried margin:0 in body?

Comment: Why the heck are you [using a frameset DTD](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsimorasic.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) when you have no frame elements?

Comment: it does not help, nor does jumping to conclusions and giving me a negative vote.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO. For this question to be useful to anyone other than yourself, please considering posting some snippets of _relevant_ code in your question. External links are likely do die, change, sprout wings and/or try to take over the world - and thus, aren't very useful for the Q&A format that is Stackoverflow. =)

Comment: if i remove the frameset dtd, which i have no idea what it is as i am learning html for the first time, it removes my navigation bar. thats when i set it to <!DOCTYPE html> only.

Comment: Please add some sample code, sample input and expected output. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/147645) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the 8px margin has been applied to body tag by the browser for a minimal formatting.
To get rid of this, you need to override the body tag css style.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

i figured out the problem, which was with the H1 tag, applying following rule will fix

```
#header H1 {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have done that! refer to the comments above. It does not fix the problem!

Comment: there was no such white space which consums 35px height in the document/page.

Comment: have another look - i re-uploaded the index file, sorry. however i have entered what you said, no change.

Comment: can you post a screenshot here?

Comment: @Kronos look at the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` has a (default, non-zero) margin (or padding in some browsers).

Set:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

… to remove it.

Comment: thanks for you quick reply, however, the code above only removed the white space that was on each side (about 5px).

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply this rule at the top of your CSS document.

```
body{margin:0;padding:0}
```

Comment: thanks for you quick reply, however, the code above only removed the white space that was on each side (about 5px).